# Mixed content on Prestashop with smartblog-v3.0.0 module

Tags: ssl, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I installed a SSL cerfificate to a website created with Prestashop 1.7. But it indicates to me that it is not totally safe since there is a request to the image of the smartblog v 3.0.0 by HTTP. Checking the code from Firefox developer tools. Previously, I tried to force the module to read photos only via https. Code editing did not produce results. From the information collected, it appears that the blog module has a problem loading photos via https. Therefore, duplicate content.

[Link to the website](https://spawber.com.pl)

[Screenshot dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzGsl.png)

Part of the smartblog.php file:

```
public static function GetSmartBlogUrl()
{
    $ssl_enable = Configuration::get('PS_SSL_ENABLED');
    $id_lang = (int) Context::getContext()->language->id;
    $id_shop = (int) Context::getContext()->shop->id;
    $rewrite_set = (int) Configuration::get('PS_REWRITING_SETTINGS');
    $ssl = null;
    static $force_ssl = null;
    if ($ssl === null) {
        if ($force_ssl === null)
            $force_ssl = (Configuration::get('PS_SSL_ENABLED') && Configuration::get('PS_SSL_ENABLED_EVERYWHERE'));
        $ssl = $force_ssl;
    }

    if (Configuration::get('PS_MULTISHOP_FEATURE_ACTIVE') && $id_shop !== null)
        $shop = new Shop($id_shop);
    else
        $shop = Context::getContext()->shop;
    $base = ($ssl == 1 && $ssl_enable == 1) ? 'https://' . $shop->domain_ssl : 'http://' . $shop->domain;
    $langUrl = Language::getIsoById($id_lang) . '/';
    if ((!$rewrite_set && in_array($id_shop, array((int) Context::getContext()->shop->id, null))) || !Language::isMultiLanguageActivated($id_shop) || !(int) Configuration::get('PS_REWRITING_SETTINGS', null, null, $id_shop))
        $langUrl = '';

    return $base . $shop->getBaseURI() . $langUrl;
}

public static function GetSmartBlogLink($rewrite = 'smartblog', $params = null, $id_shop = null, $id_lang = null)
{
    $url = smartblog::GetSmartBlogUrl();
    $dispatcher = Dispatcher::getInstance();
    $id_lang = (int) Context::getContext()->language->id;
    $force_routes = (bool) Configuration::get('PS_REWRITING_SETTINGS');
    if ($params != null) {
        return $url . $dispatcher->createUrl($rewrite, $id_lang, $params, $force_routes);
    } else {
        $params = array();
        return $url . $dispatcher->createUrl($rewrite, $id_lang, $params, $force_routes);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

which template of smartblog that is not displaying correctly the images via https? I found a issue in that module a few weeks ago, just check the variable who is printing the route.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem loading the post images with ssl actived. Just replacing the code in the line http://  for https:// .  clear the cache and works.